# Create directories from filenames with multiple words

Tags: linux, bash, directory, filenames

I have several files in one directory in Linux that look like:

```
John Smith-data.txt
Peter Walker-address.txt
...
```

I want a script that reads these filenames and creates one directory for each name in the filename, that is

```
John Smith
Peter Walker
```

If  I do

```
for name in `ls | awk -F - '{print $1}'`; do mkdir $name; done
```

the following directories are created

```
John
Smith
Peter
Walker
```

by doing

```
for name in `ls | awk -F - '{print $1}'`; do mkdir "$name"; done
```

I get the same result

Then, doing

```
for name in "`ls | awk -F - '{print $1}'"`; do mkdir "$name"; done
```

creeates only one dir named:

```
John Smith Peter Walker
```

Finaly, if I enter

```
for name in "`ls | awk -F - '{print $1}'"`; do mkdir $name; done
```

again I get

```
John
Smith
Peter
Walker
```

Any ideas ? How to use the quotes `""` ?

Thanks in advance

Xavier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want, but perhaps:

```
for i in *.txt; do mkdir "${i%-*}"; done
```